# ebtables drop / limit smtp port

Tags: networking, iptables, kvm, qemu, bridge

I am using bridged devices, main node runs on CentOS 7 and Guest are KVM VM's.

I have tried rules as below on host node to block port 25 but was not successful.

```
ebtables -A FORWARD -p IPv4 --ip-protocol tcp --ip-dst $IP --ip-dport 25 -j DROP
ebtables -A FORWARD -p IPv4 --ip-protocol tcp --ip-src $IP --ip-sport 25 -j DROP
```

Questions:

1. Am i doing in the right way. (Should I use OUTPUT/INPUT chain instead of FORWARD)
2. Could there be an option to limit (throttle) number of connection per minute. (Example use case: Limit number of emails send per minute)
3. Can i specify multiple ports in ebtables rules.